# Gradle "setup" tasks (pre-build / compile / jar)

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

Relatively new to java and gradle -- trying to do things "right". Prior to building my application (I've added the gradle "application" plugin) I want to setup some environment and system things -- for example, I'd like to create the log/ directory and log.txt file.

So I'm doing something like:

```
task setup {
    println 'Setup task executing ...'

    File d = new File('log');
    d.mkdir();
    f = new File(d.getPath() + '/log.txt');
    f.createNewFile();
}
```

Which works -- but I get a bunch of stdout warnings when running > gradle setup

```
Setup task executing ...
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "f" on "task ':setup'", value: "log/log.txt".
:setup UP-TO-DATE
```

So one question: What is the correct way to leverage Gradle to perform setup / installation tasks? (This should only really be executed once, when the application is deployed)

Comment: This concrete warning - "properties on demand deprecated" - is caused by undeclated variable "f" in this code. The effect is the following: "f" is created as "extension" variable to the current Project object. You should either declare a local variable or use project.ext to eliminate this warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, you are mixing task [configuration and execution](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).  This:

```
task foo {
    // Stuff
}
```

is not the same as this:

```
task foo << {
    // Stuff
}
```

In the first, "stuff" is run at configuration time, leading to the warnings that you're seeing (because `f` is interpreted as a project variable during this phase).  In the second, it's run at execution time.

(Gradle is great, but this very subtle syntax distinction can be the source of many infuriating bugs!)

---

As for how to do setup properly, as you're using the Application plugin, you should look into *[Including other resources in the distribution](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#application_distribution_resources)*.

(You should also consider moving the directory-creation logic into your application itself, as ideally you want it to be robust against someone deleting the log directory!)

Comment: OK -- thanks. Will do (both read up on the add'l docs and move the logic into the application).

Comment: ad "this very subtle syntax distinction can be the source of many infuriating bugs": This is why I always recommend to use `doLast` instead of `<<`.